# Problems with Implementing History in a Simple UNIX Shell

Tags: c, unix

I'm trying to implement a history feature for a simple shell. The history should hold the last 10 commands executed. I placed my code below, but I am running into some problems.

First, when I enter one (or two) commands and type in `history`to display the history, nothing is displayed. But, when I enter a few more commands, the entire history is displayed (like it should), but a string of zero's is displayed next to each history index.

What am I doing wrong, and how can I fix this?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>

#define MAX_LINE 80 /* 80 chars per line, per command, should be enough. */

char *history[10][MAX_LINE];
int placePointer;


/**
 * setup() reads in the next command line, separating it into distinct tokens
 * using whitespace as delimiters. setup() sets the args parameter as a 
 * null-terminated string.
 */

void setup(char inputBuffer[], char *args[],int *background)
{
    int length, /* # of characters in the command line */
        i,      /* loop index for accessing inputBuffer array */
        start,  /* index where beginning of next command parameter is */
        ct;     /* index of where to place the next parameter into args[] */

    ct = 0;

    /* read what the user enters on the command line */
    length = read(STDIN_FILENO, inputBuffer, MAX_LINE);  

    start = -1;
    if (length == 0)
        exit(0);            /* ^d was entered, end of user command stream */
    if (length < 0){
        perror("error reading the command");
        exit(-1);           /* terminate with error code of -1 */
    }

    /* examine every character in the inputBuffer */
    for (i = 0; i < length; i++) { 
        switch (inputBuffer[i]){
        case ' ':
        case '\t' :               /* argument separators */
            if(start != -1){
                args[ct] = &inputBuffer[start];    /* set up pointer */
                ct++;
            }
            inputBuffer[i] = '\0'; /* add a null char; make a C string */
            start = -1;
            break;

        case '\n':                 /* should be the final char examined */
            if (start != -1){
                args[ct] = &inputBuffer[start];     
                ct++;
            }
            inputBuffer[i] = '\0';
            args[ct] = NULL; /* no more arguments to this command */
            break;

        case '&':
            *background = 1;
            inputBuffer[i] = '\0';
            break;

        default :             /* some other character */
            if (start == -1)
                start = i;
        } 
    }    
    args[ct] = NULL; /* just in case the input line was > 80 */
} 

void displayHistory(){
    printf("Display History:\n");
    int i = placePointer;
    int j;
    int counter;
    while(counter < 10) {
        printf("%d: ",counter);
        for (j = 0; j < MAX_LINE; j++) {
          printf("%d",history[i][j]);
        }
        printf("\n");
        i = (i + 1) % 10;
        counter++;
    }
}
/*
void runHistoryAt(int index){
    printf("Run History At:\n");
    char *arg1 = &history[placePointer + index][0];
    char *argLine[MAX_LINE/2+1];
    int j;
    for (j = 0; j < MAX_LINE/2+1; j++) {
      *argLine[j] = history[placePointer + index][j];
    }
    execvp(arg1,argLine);
}*/

int main(void)
{
    char inputBuffer[MAX_LINE]; /* buffer to hold the command entered */
    int background;             /* equals 1 if a command is followed by '&' */
    char *args[MAX_LINE/2+1];/* command line (of 80) has max of 40 arguments */


    while (1){            /* Program terminates normally inside setup */
        background = 0;
        printf("COMMAND->");
            fflush(0);
            setup(inputBuffer, args, &background);       /* get next command */

        /* the steps are:
         (1) fork a child process using fork()
         (2) the child process will invoke execvp()
         (3) if background == 0, the parent will wait, 
            otherwise returns to the setup() function. */

        pid_t pid = fork();
        printf("Fork created.\n");


        if(pid < 0){
            printf("Fork failed.\n");
        }else if(pid == 0){
            if( strcmp(args[0],"history") == 0){ /*  Print History */
                displayHistory();
            }else if(strcmp(args[0],"r") == 0){ /*  r num */
                int index = (int) args[1];
                /*runHistoryAt( index - 1);*/
            }else if(strcmp(args[0],"rr") == 0){ /*  Run recent */
                /*runHistoryAt(0);*/
            }else{  /*  Execute normally */
                printf("executing..., adding to history buffer\n");
                /* Add args to history buffer */
                int j;
                for (j = 0; j < sizeof(args); j++) {
                    history[placePointer][j] = args[j];
                }
                placePointer = (placePointer + 1) % 10;
                /* Execute!  */
                execvp(args[0],args);
            }
        }

        if(background == 0){
            wait(NULL);
        }else{
          setup(inputBuffer, args, &background);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Seriously, you are best placed to debug this yourself.  Asking strangers to spot the errors in your code by inspection is not productive.

Answer (score 1):

All of your `args` pointers are pointers into your `inputBuffer`, which contains the most recent line of input entered.  So when you save the `args` to the `history` you're just saving pointers, not the actual pointed at strings, which are still (only) in the `inputBuffer`.  When you read the next command, it overwrites the `inputBuffer` making all your saved `history` pointers invalid -- they now point at some piece of the current command and not at the old command.

Comment: So, would a way to fix this be that I should save the values in history, rather than pointers? And how would I do that?

Comment: @user906153, hey do you by any chance have the working code for this or figure out and remember why your code did not work?